# How to validate angular form only on submit even at form active validation state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form where I have to validate only on submitting form which I did successfully using following angular synatax

```
form1.inputvalue.$invalid && form1.$submitted
```

Now once the error is being displayed and it starts validating values on change of input(or keyup) on live. My customer dont want to validate it on keyup., and message should be hidden on making change of input and should validate again back on clicking submit button for 2nd time. Sounds weird but required :) .

I tried ng-hide="true" on ng-change of input. But its not triggering in console. Can u help me where am I missing

```js
$scope.hidevalidate = function(){
  console.log("coming to hide");
  $scope.hidevalidation = true;
  console.log("hidden");
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmdata" novalidate>
<input type="text" 
       class="class1"  
       name="item1" 
       ng-model="frmdata.item1" 
       id="item" 
       ng-change="hidevalidate()"
       ng-blur="focusout('item1');"
       ng-disabled="disableItem1"
       ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{1,25})?$/"
       ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
  </input>
<div ng-show="frmdata.item1.$invalid && form1.$submitted" >
<div ng-hide="hidevalidation" class="error-message">Item should not be empty (or) only numbers allowed</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add some more code of how you are doing it or create a plunkr

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form1.$setPristine()` to mark the form as it is brand new, so theoretically it should be as if you come to the page for the first time (so if your logic handles this correctly for the first time, it should after this as well).

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Tried $setPristine., but not working. After little googling, I found that it can set validation reset stages to $dirty but not $invalid.. So I even changed my error messages to form1.item.$dirty., but still not triggering. I tried debug, Breakpoint is entering the function and setting $setpristine 'Undefined'

Answer (score 0):

You could call a method when clicking the submit button that does all the checking, and add the attribute novalidate to the form so it doesn't check anything, since this method would check everything and set all errors (if any).